# Busqueda avanzada mediante boton

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

He estado buscando la manera en hacer la tipica busqueda en la barra de navegacion pero esta vez mediante un boton con apariencia de link, pretendo hacer un filtro tipo MercadoLibre

Este es mi codigo:

```
<?php session_start();

require 'extras/config.php';
require 'functions.php';

comprobarSession();

$conexion = conexion($bd_config);
if (!$conexion) {
    header('Location: error.php');
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' && !empty($_GET['1000'])) {
    $busqueda = limpiarDatos($_GET['1000']);

    $statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM publications WHERE salario LIKE :1000');

    $statement->execute(array(':1000' => "%$busqueda%"));
    $resultados = $statement->fetchAll();
    print_r($statement);

    if(empty($resultados)){
        $titulo = 'No se encontraron articulos con el resultado '. $busqueda;
    } else {
        $titulo = 'Resultados de la busqueda: ' . $busqueda;
    }
} 

require 'views/1000+.php';

?>
```

y mi boton es este:

```
<form action="1000+.php" method="GET">
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-link" value="$1,000+">$1,000+</input>(16947)
</form>
```

Comment: ¿y el problema es?

Comment: @JorgeArturoJuarez el problema es que no manda la variable por get, ni trae nada, realizo un var_dump y aun asi no muestra ningun arreglo ni nada

Comment: `salario LIKE '%1000%'`?  no seria `salario > 1000-500 and salario < 1000+500 `?

Comment: tal vez, parte del problema sea ese, pero el otro detalle es que en verdad no manda la variable por get, no la muestra en la url, solo hace la accion como boton y redirecciona a la pagina de 1000

Comment: y si usas `<a href='tupagina.php?limit=1000'> `y `$_GET['limit']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero busca cambiar el nombre del archivo por otro como `1000more.php` evita caracteres especiales en los nombres.

Segundo, los inputs en HTML no son etiquetas cerrables, hacer esto:

`<input type="submit" class="btn btn-link" value="$1,000+">$1,000+</input>(16947)`

Está totalmente erróneo, deberás hacerlo así:

`<input type="submit" class="btn btn-link" value="$1,000+" />(16947)`

Y listo, para empezar, tercero:

`<form action="1000+.php" method="GET">`

Ahí no ocupas necesariamente que haya por método GET, puedes mandarlo por POST de igual forma, si lo que quieres por GET pues entonces podrías hacerlo de otra forma haciendo que JS se encargue de la redirección para generar una query especial de la URL codificada para evitar que, te salgan "caracteres raros" y después sencillamente los decodificas. Ya que el navegador lo hace, pero por ejemplo `Hola%20mundo` deberías buscar hacerlo como `Hola+mundo` como preferente (es dato extra, no es necesariamente que se haga de esta forma).

## Parte del error

Ahora bien, aquí está el error:

Tu haces un form que envía un valor sin nombre, es decir:
Tu url luciría algo como:
`http://localhost/1000+.php?1000`

Pero como tal no hay valor, entonces es "empty" la parte $_GET['1000']

Lo que ocupas es hacer un input extra, algo para que tu form quede así:

```
<form action="1000+.php" method="GET">
   <input type="hidden" value="1000" name="valor" />
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-link" name="send">$1,000+</input>(16947)
</form>
```

Y entonces en vez de `!empty($_GET['1000'])` usarías algo como: `!empty($_GET['valor'])` y debería obtener el valor ya que la URL luciría correcta pero incluiría el name "send" de la URL luciendo:

`http://localhost/1000+.php?valor=1000&send`

Si no me equivoco, cualquier cosa, coméntame qué pasa con los cambios y seguir para dar la solución.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta funciona, manda el valor por GET pero no funciona al 100%, creo que el error esta en el codigo ya que me dice `No se encontraron articulos con el resultado 1000` y la URL luce `http://localhost/talvez%20usuario/1000more.php?valor=1000&send=1%2C000`

Comment: Disculpa, por copiar y pegar tu código olvidé que debes quitar el "</input>" como comento al inicio para que ya no salga ese "&send=..." ahora bien, lo otro es por tu consulta, eso ya es cosa tuya para alterar como dice arriba cambia la consulta ya que tu pregunta era el por qué no accedía a esa zona. Saludos y te encargo mejor respuesta [? :P

Comment: Oh claro, si pude solucionar el problema, ya me muestra los resultados, aunque ahora el problema es al momento de hacer la paginacion, ya que al cambiar de pagina quita todos los valores get, pero estoy pensando en solucionarlo con un scroll infinito ;)